# Max values for each sub queries in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am using below mentioned query for getting difference and percentage change > 30  between two quarters for Costcenter, Vendor and Tool. The output is like for Costcenter, vendor and tool:[image]

I want to get a result which will give for a costcenter the max difference followed by max vendor for that costcenter  and max tool for that vendor e.g For costcenter A, vendor c is the max and for vendor c max tool is 4.

[image]

Query which i am using is:

```
select ccv.Costcenter,
       (cc.sumq3 - cc.sumq2) as costcenter_diff, ((((cc.sumq3 - cc.sumq2)/cc.sumq2)*100) ) as Costcenter_change, ccv.Vendor,
       (ccv.sumq3 - ccv.sumq2) as venor_diff, ((((ccv.sumq3 - ccv.sumq2)/ccv.sumq2)*100)) as Vendor_change, ccvt.Tool,(ccvt.sumq3 - ccvt.sumq2) as Tool_diff,((((ccvt.sumq3 - ccvt.sumq2)/ccvt.sumq2)*100)) as Tool_Change
from (select Costcenter,
             sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q2' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq2,
             sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q3' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq3
      from Glm_Test.CostCenter_Rawdata
      where quarter in ('15/16 Q3', '15/16 Q2')
      group by Costcenter
     ) cc join
     (select Costcenter, Vendor,
             sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q2' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq2,
             sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q3' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq3
      from Glm_Test.CostCenter_Rawdata
      where quarter in ('15/16 Q3', '15/16 Q2')
      group by Costcenter, Vendor
     ) ccv join
     (select Costcenter, Vendor,Tool,
             sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q2' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq2,
             sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q3' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq3
      from Glm_Test.CostCenter_Rawdata
      where quarter in ('15/16 Q3', '15/16 Q2')
      group by Costcenter, Vendor,Tool
     ) ccvt
     on cc.Costcenter = ccv.Costcenter and ccv.Vendor=ccvt.Vendor and cc.Costcenter = ccvt.Costcenter
    Having  Costcenter_change > 30  and Vendor_change > 30 and tool_change >30  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean that Vendor is the max? he has the maximal sales for the costcenter?

I would advise you to use partitioning to find the maximals, also you can use it without the need to join the data three times.

For example use:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Costcenter ORDER BY sumq3-sumq2)
```

For costcenters where sumq3 and sumq2 will be the sums with cases in your script.

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Costcenter,Vendor ORDER BY sumq3-sumq2)
```

For vendors etc.

Then from that output select only where all three ranks are 1.

You will also need to do columns for the respective sumq3 and sumq2 to know the partitioned results.

I hope that helps.

Edit: Try this:

```
with costs as
(     
select Costcenter,
Vendor,
Tool,
sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q2' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq2,
sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q3' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq3
from Glm_Test.CostCenter_Rawdata
where quarter in ('15/16 Q3', '15/16 Q2')
group by Costcenter,Vendor,Tool
)
select Costcenter,sum(sumq3)-sum(sumq2) over (partition by Costcenter)     as Costcenter_diff
Vendor,sum(sumq3)-sum(sumq2) over (partition by Costcenter,Vendor) as     Vendor_diff,
Tool,sum(sumq3)-sum(sumq2) over (partition by Costcenter,Vendor,Tool) as     Tool_diff
   from costs
```

Comment: Yes, that means maximal sales for the costcenter. I am new to mySQL. Thanks for the suggestion but i am not able to get it how to implement in query.If possible can you please make changes in posted query?

Comment: To be honest your explanation in the question are a bit shaky for me. Try to start with this and extract the things you need - see my edit in the answer